# AppScript execution in mail merge - best practices for reliability and stability

Tags: google-apps-script

Please verify if I'm not running into problems in regards to script execution.
I've got FIVE Google forms, all bound to ONE Google sheet. The sheet has the below code attached to it (I've stripped the code from error handling etc).

**Scenario:**

I'm trying to issue certificates for users of 5 different courses. On course completion (at around same time of the day) users enter their details (name surname, email) and the script below takes care of creating and sending personalised certificates to their email addresses. 
Say, there's a maximum of 100 users per day on all courses.

**Here are the questions :)**

- Is this reasonable to manage five forms from one sheet and rely on
  single script?
- If not how would you do it?

I'm thinking about how script is executed? Is it an instance per submition, or will there be a queue of 100 jobs to be served from one sheet? I know javascript runs one thing at a time, but am not entirely sure what it means in terms of running app script and onFormSubmit event - I just don't know how exactly those scripts/instances are managed and executed.

This is my second attempt to issue certificates for multiple forms. The previous solution had one sheet per form, and five scripts generating certificates, but it was pain the back to make any changes and testing it.

Many thanks for any answer.

Best.
Rafal

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var chosenId;

var templates = {
  "templateId_PL_1" : "1oS_11gz_123456789abcdefghijklmnop",
  "templateId_PL_2" : "11gasdsz_123456789abcdefghijklmnop",
  "templateId_PL_3" : "1JMo11gz_123456789abcdefghijklmnop",
  "templateId_EN_1" : "1KTx11gz_123456789abcdefghijklmnop",
  "templateId_EN_2" : "1_VQBgsz_123456789abcdefghijklmnop",
}
// reaction to form submit event
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  //check source of data by getting sheet name, i.e. "PL_1" or "EN_2"
  var range = e.range;
  chosenId = range.getSheet().getName();
  //get corresponding named range in "master" worksheet
  var trainingData = ss.getRangeByName(chosenId).getValues();
  //create new user object
  var userData = {
    //get submitted data from post
    "Title":[e.values[1]],
    "Name":[e.values[2]],
    "Surname":[e.values[3]],
    "Email":[e.values[4]],
    //get data from named range
    "Client":[trainingData[1][0]],
    "Training":[trainingData[1][3]],              
    "Date":[trainingData[1][1]],
     };
  //generate certs
  createAndUpdateCertificate(userData);
 }


function createAndUpdateCertificate(userObj){
  //create template copy according to data source
  var tempId = "templateId_"+chosenId; 
  var copy = DriveApp.getFileById(templates[tempId]).makeCopy("temp");
  var presentationID = copy.getId();
  //open copied presentation and go to 1st (only) slide
  var presentation = SlidesApp.openById(presentationID);
  var firstSlide = presentation.getSlides()[0]
  //replace texts in the slide
  firstSlide.replaceAllText("<<Title>>", userObj.Title);
  firstSlide.replaceAllText("<<Name>>", userObj.Name);
  firstSlide.replaceAllText("<<Surname>>", userObj.Surname);
  firstSlide.replaceAllText("<<Training>>", userObj.Training);
  firstSlide.replaceAllText("<<Date>>", userObj.Date);
  //close the copy
  presentation.saveAndClose();

  //sending certs
  sendCerts(
    presentationID, 
    userObj.Email, 
    userObj.Name, 
    userObj.Surname, 
    userObj.Training, 
    userObj.Date
  );

  //delete copy
  copy.setTrashed(true);
}


function sendCerts(cert, email, name, surname, training, date){
 //fetch cert as pdf
 var docblob = DriveApp.getFileById(cert).getAs('application/pdf');
 docblob.setName(date+"-"+"CERT "+training+"-"+name+" "+surname+".pdf");
 //save the pdf in appropriate  folder as a backup
 var dest = DriveApp.getFolderById("1K2k-123456789abcdefghijklmnop")
 var file = dest.createFile(docblob);
    MailApp.sendEmail(
    email, 
    "test", // title
    "test", // body
    { noReply: true,
     attachments: [file]
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't look at it real close but using the range to get the response sheet name is the key to handling multiple forms in the same spreadsheet.  It looks like your forms are very similar so that makes things a lot easier.  Why didn't you just sendCerts one object rather than all individual parameters?  Overall, I think the code looks well organized.